# Where is the official Iranian Railways website?

Tags: trains, online-resources, iran

This sounds odd, but my friend and I are struggling to find the official site for Iranian Railways.  Any google search we do takes us to:

[IranRail.net](http://www.iranrail.net/)

Which describes itself as the "UNOFFICIAL Homepage of Iranian Railways".

Unofficial? OK, but then were is the official one? Or is there not one, which makes this the defacto option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the site at http://www.rai.ir/ but AFAIK it's Persian only. I am slightly curious as to what you searched for on Google, really:
[image: Google search for iranian railways]

Comment: Bizarre, same search and I'm getting the Unofficial link at the top, and the rai.ir doesn't even appear. Joy of custom google search results? Thanks! Now to investigate translation of it.

Comment: Maybe it's because different localised versions of google will give out different results. When I (Singapore) search for 'iranian railways', that given result is much lower in the results and not knowing Persian, it wouldn't be obvious to me as well that that's the one.

Comment: Wonder why the Unofficial one ranks so much higher, too....

Comment: "it wouldn't be obvious to me as well that that's the one" -- the wikipedia result summary has the name RAI so the URL is immediately suspicious.

Comment: Searching from the US, the official site comes up at #10 in the search results, even lower than in your screenshot. And now we have another web design firm to add to the list of firms to never engage.

Comment: @chx You can Find English version of the site [here](http://www.rai.ir/index.aspx?tempname=engmain2&lang=2&sub=0&epageId=543&isPopUp=false) or just click on English on top-left corner of the official page

Answer (score 6):

The official Iranian Railways company is IRIR (or [RAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Republic_of_Iran_Railways) - not the famous [Rai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAI)). Its main website is the one @chx mentioned - I should correct it does have a tiny (useless) [English version](http://www.rai.ir/index.aspx?tempname=int&lang=2&sub=0&epageId=624&isPopUp=false) though.

A main associate company of RAI is RAJA which comes with a slightly better [website](http://www.raja.ir/Index.aspx?tempname=EnRaja&lang=2&sub=0) . RAJA once completely belonged to RAI (~ until 2010) but now its shares are partially given to another organization due to privatization plans of government.

Why Google doesn't give priority to the RAI main website? ~ Poor (terrible?!) [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) in the English version - if you search in Persian it does recognize the official website:

[image: Iranian Railway]